# Unable to write to file in Android, Read-Only Filesystem

Tags: java, android, filestream, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write a file in Android.

```
private void writeScoreToFile(BlastScore result)
    {
        try{
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(CaptureActivity.BLAST_SCORES,true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(Integer.toString(result.getBlastScore()));
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Write Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

```
10-28 21:04:11.200: W/System.err(669): Write Error: /BlastScores.txt (Read-only file system)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to write to the root directory. You probably want to be writing to your app's directory, not root.

To do that, use [Context.openFileInput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29) and [Context.openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `new FileWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it is trying to write a file to the filesystem root. Your application is only allowed write to specific folders.

Found this on an article:

```
/data/data/your_project_package_structure/files/
```